# Android OpenVPN issue in Android KitKat 4.4.2

Tags: android, openvpn

Hi I have an issue in connecting to OpenVPN for android kitkat 4.4.2 by Arne Schwabe. I have an ovpn profile file which I am importing to the app to connect. there is no issue in connecting. But once the connection is established I am not able to browse internet.

Can anybody tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I attempted to fix by using tcp connection only on port 443 which allowed me to connect, but OpenVPN continues to disconnect,look for routes, reconnect and endlessly do this. I have tried everything to no avail. Even the L2TP Android menu option is having problems. I am on Asus ME181C (Intel) running Android 4.4.2